# Laravel 8 - Eloquent Relationship cannot access relation properties / values

Tags: laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

Model 1: Walks

```
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Device','device_uuid','device_uuid');
   }
```

Model 2: Device

```
  public function walks() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Walks','device_uuid','device_uuid');
    }
```

In my index file:

```
     <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Walk Date</th>
                <th>Device Name</th>
                <th>In</th>
                <th>Out</th>
                <th width="280px">Action</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach ($walks as $walk)

            <tr>
                    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $walk->walk_datetime }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $walk->device->device_uuid }}</td> <========
                    <td>{{ $walk->walk_in }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $walk->walk_out }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('walks.destroy',$walk->id) }}" method="POST">

                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('walks.edit',$walk->id) }}">Edit</a>

                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </table>
```

this causes errors:

```
<td>{{ $walk->device->device_uuid }}</td> <========
```

"Trying to get property 'device_uuid' of non-object"

If I do this:

```
<td>{{ $walk->device }}</td>
```

I get:

```
{"id":1,"device_uuid":"1902101300368","device_name":"Test 1","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}
```

which means the relation works correct.

Is there any other way that I should use to access the "device_mame" attribute?

Related to questions below.. All walks has a valid device linked.

1. walks list. This is what shows if I print ->  $walk->device
   [image]
2. walk list (DB)
   [image]
3. devices list (DB)
   [image]

Comment: Are you sure that every `Walk` in the loop has an associated `Device`?

Comment: Yeap, please see the attached images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) It seems to me that some `Walks` don't have a `Device`. That's why it (usually) throws that error.

Similar problem on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/simple-belongsto-relationship-throws-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object).

Or what you can do is use ternary operators

```
<td>{{(isset($walk->device->device_uuid)? $walk->device->device_uuid : ''}}</td>
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't look to be this issue. As u can see in images i attached all records are connected.

Comment: Eventually the above worked. Many thanks!